# aws route53 - get DNS A record of a private IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-cli, amazon-route53

Basically it's a `--filter`\ `--query` question because the docs are kind of messy, what I'm trying to get is the A record in route53 of a specific ip address.

Of course I have this:

```
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id XXXX123XX
```

Which outputs a json with all of my existing records on the specified zone, but to filter a specific IP from it and get not the IP but the actual DNS record, I couldn't figure out how to get besides cutting it with bash tools.

Desired output:

```
my-record.my-domain.com
```

Can you guys help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Dennis' answer, if you really don't want to use OS tools:

```
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id XXXX123XX --query "ResourceRecordSets[?ResourceRecords[?Value == '34.252.xxx.yyy']].Name" --output=text
```

Answer (score 4):

Example:

```
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id Z3MANQ630XXXXX --query "ResourceRecordSets[?ResourceRecords[?Value == '10.100.125.42']]"
```

Filtering output:

```
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id Z3MANQ630XXXXX --query "ResourceRecordSets[?ResourceRecords[?Value == '10.100.125.42']]" |jq -r .[].Name
```